# pass from form to javascript variable to display in alert

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a page with a form that I've validated with javascript. It works great, but now I want to show what the user has entered into the form in the javascript alert. I was thinking that if I set variables to get what's entered into the form, I could  use that in the alert. Am I getting confused with PHP (I can't use php as this is for a course assignment on javascript).
This is the alert from the javascript:

```
confirm('Please check your details.');
    return true
```

I was thinking that if I set up a variable at the top of my form validation function, something like this:

```
var  form_name = form_object.txtname.value;
```

But one for each input in the form, then I could use an alert statement like this:

```
confirm('Please check your details.'form_name);
    return true
```

And then put every variable for each form input in the alert message. Am I even close?

Comment: You are thinking right. Check it and return if u got any errors

Comment: maybe some more code would help.

Comment: You want to put something in an `alert` or in `confirm`?

Comment: Confirm: So I can display what the user has inputed, ask them if it's correct and if so, they click on ok and get a message saying the information has been submitted. If the information is not correct, tell them to click on cancel which will return them to the form.

Comment: Ok, so I made it put the information entered into the form on the alert (or confirm) by setting up my variables like this: `var  form_name = document.forms.project.txtname.value;` and then the confirm statement is like this: `confirm(form_name); return true`. But I have multiple inputs on the form and want them all to display. I tried having my confirm like this: `confirm(form_name,form_email)` and having all the variables in there but it only shows the first one. How could I get them all to show?